# Flutter: Betterplayer iOS Picture-in-Picture(Pip) mode

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-video-player, picture-in-picture

I using https://jhomlala.github.io/betterplayer for flutter video player.

When enable Picture-in-Picture(Pip) mode, the original video still remain and still playing. Suppose to showing black blank screen.

I not understand swift or objective-c, so that I not sure is it a bug from the [iOS code](https://github.com/jhomlala/betterplayer/tree/master/ios)

[image]